# Ngrx 8 - dispatch multiple else if conditions with multiple actions in effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, effect

I am looking for the solution, for below situation:

```
 startMultpileActionDepensOnType$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(startMultpileActionDepensOnType),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectTypeActions)),
        map(([action, select]) => {
                const actionType = select.type.toLowerCase();

                if (actionType === ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_FIRST.toLowerCase()) {
                    return [getInitialDataStatus({statusType: 'disabled'}),
                        fetchImportantDataFirst()];
                } else if (actionType === ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_SECOND.toLowerCase()) {
                    return [getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataSecond());
                } else if (actionType === ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_THIRD.toLowerCase()] {
                    return [getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataThidr()];
                }
            }
        )
    ));
```

So:
 - I would like to run multiple action in array,
 - and using multiple else if case

I tried fixed it by dictionary... but maybe there is a much better solution.

Comment: use case switch can simply the code.

Comment: That same... maybe there is any better solution.

Comment: Like you said you can use pre definied object/dictionary to store action key and action function as well

Comment: That's why I am asking for help, because I have still problem to do it.

Comment: i'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how you can use object to cut the if/else, in addition maybe something can also be improve with the enum compare here, it just seem a bit awkward

```
const functionMap={
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_FIRST.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({statusType: 'disabled'}),fetchImportantDataFirst()],
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_SECOND.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataSecond()],
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_THIRD.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataThidr()]
}

 startMultpileActionDepensOnType$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(startMultpileActionDepensOnType),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectTypeActions)),
        map(([action, select]) => {
                const actionType = select.type.toLowerCase();
                return functionMap[actionType]

            }
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you. Have you idea, why I can't add const in effect file? I can do it only in map. Outside - not.

Comment: effect is a class, you can add functonMap as a class static property

Comment: hmm You mean create another class with export const and use it in current effect file?

Comment: I personally think it is totally ok to put the functionMap outside of class but in the same file

Comment: Thank you for your all help. But if I put in in readonly, const, public static... I can't do that in that same file.

Comment: If u want to put functionMap in effect class as class property, you can always reference it with this.functionMap

Comment: Yes, I know. But I got the TS2576 error - property functionMap is a static member

Comment: Umm. I think if you can setup a simple stackbliz I can help look into that. It should be something quite simple

Comment: Oh, I got! I must wrote ```private functionMap: {} = {...} ``` with :{}. Without this - does not work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, now I have got - ```Action must have a type property```. RXJS is not easy. TS is not easy.

Comment: Ya that’s another big topic

Comment: Awesome... Hmm so it is not the good idea, to use dictionary?